# UDK weapon on first person not showing up

Tags: udk, unreal

I've been following this tutorial
http://www.moug-portfolio.info/udk-weapon-basics/

all my code is the same as the page...

except here

```
DefaultPropeties
{
Begin Object Name=GunMesh
    SkeletalMesh=SkeletalMesh'WP_LinkGun.Mesh.SK_WP_Linkgun_3P'
    HiddenGame=FALSE
    HiddenEditor=FALSE
end object

Mesh=GunMesh
Components.Add(GunMesh)
}
```

i had to replace begin object for this

```
Begin Object Class=SkeletalMeshComponent Name=GunMesh
```

i think i might have forgot to add a model/skeletal so i dont have anywhere to attach the weapon to? How can I do that??

Can some UnrealScript expert please look to it for me or give me a valid tutorial link for creating a custom weapon?

thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that I was missing a model to attach the weapon to like I suspected

just added this code to my default props on my pawn class and everything went ok

```
Begin Object class=SkeletalMeshComponent Name=SkeletalMeshComponent0
    SkeletalMesh=SkeletalMesh'CH_IronGuard_Male.Mesh.SK_CH_IronGuard_MaleA'
    AnimSets(0)=AnimSet'CH_AnimHuman.Anims.K_AnimHuman_BaseMale'
    AnimTreeTemplate=AnimTree'AT_CH_Human'
    PhysicsAsset=PhysicsAsset'SK_CH_Corrupt_Male_Physics'
    //bHasPhysicsAssetInstance=True
    bEnableSoftBodySimulation=True
    bSoftBodyAwakeOnStartup=True
End Object
Mesh=SkeletalMeshComponent0
Components.Add(SkeletalMeshComponent0)
```